# Define bean in Spring application context at startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, dependency-injection

I have some issues in registering some classes in the `ApplicationContext` as bean at Spring application startup.

I have an interface named `Setting` and many classes inherited from this and I have a `SettingService` which is responsible to load and save these settings. I'd want to use these settings in the Spring DI system. I know I can put `@component` annotation on above these classes, **But these classes in addition to behavior have state and I want to load these states from the database using `SettingService`.**

`SettingService` interface:

```
interface SettingService {
  fun <T : Setting> loadSetting(type: KClass<T>, env: String = AppConfig.DEVELOPMENT_ENV): Mono<T>
}
```

Example usage of `Setting` interface:

```
interface Setting

class DriverSettings : Setting {
  var driverAbsentPenalty: Int = 0
}
```

---

Now for define these classes as bean, I'm doing something like this:

```
@Configuration
class SettingsConfiguration {
  @Bean
  fun registerDriverSettings(settingService: SettingService, appConfig: AppConfig): DriverSettings {
    return loadSettings(DriverSettings::class, settingService, appConfig, logger)
  }

  private fun <T : Setting> loadSettings(
    clazz: KClass<out T>,
    settingService: SettingService,
    appConfig: AppConfig
  ): T {
    val settings = settingService.loadSetting(clazz, appConfig.springProfilesActive).block()!!
    return settings
  }
}
```

But I don't want to do that for every setting Is defined in my domain I want to find all of them and register them as a `bean` in the `ApplicationContext` at startup.

I've tried `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` but in that step, I cannot use `SettingService`.

I came from .NET Core, I used `IServiceCollection` and `IServiceProvider` to achieve this. but I don't know how to do this in Spring

Comment: Have you checked Component Scanning?

Comment: And why exactly does it not work? Usually Spring has no problems autowiring the needed in this case SettingsService to the `@Bean` definition method that needs it to be instantiated.

Comment: @JAsgarov _I don't want to do that for every setting Is defined in my domain I want to find all of them and register them as a bean in the ApplicationContext at startup._

Comment: default scope of a `@Bean` is singleton. So unless you change it there is only one object instance of your Setting Bean that is created once at a startup.